# Finding the equation of a hyperbola given the vertices and foci.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

A hyperbola has the vertices $(0,0)$ and $(0,-16)$ and the foci $(0,2)$ and $(0,-18)$. Find the equation with the given information.

Comment: Please show what form you assumed and work done one so far.

Comment: So far the work I've been able to gather is [(x^2)/a^2]-[(y+16)^2/b^2] I'm unsure on how to find the value for "a" or "b"

Comment: You are not off to a good start.

Comment: I agree. It's frustrating. The text we have for class doesn't state how to find an equation from information as such.

Comment: Where would be the fun in plugging numbers into an equation that the text has provided for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your vertices and foci lie on the y axis.  This means that your hyperbola opens upward.

Equation for a generic hyperbola that opens upward:

$-\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-v)^2}{b^2} = 1$

The center $(h,v)$ lies at the mid-point between the two foci.

$a$ = distance from center to each vertex.

$c^2 = a^2+b^2$, Where c is the distance from the center to the focus.

Comment: Okay, what would value of "b" equal then?

Comment: There is enough information given to find a, and c.  And based on what I have written what do you think that says about b?

Comment: I think I've got it! I found b to equal 6. I think I can take it from here!

Answer (score 0):

The hyperbola is opening up in direction $y:$

$$ a = 8;\, b = 6;  c = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2 } = a\,e =10\,;$$

Carefully choose sign to shift axis downward so the top vertex touches x-axis.

$$ \dfrac{(y+a)^2}{a^2}  - \dfrac {x^2}{b^2} =1. $$